# Where's the toolbar in Monodevelop

Tags: configuration, toolbar, monodevelop

I'm playing around with Monodevelop and coming from Visual Studio I'm generally pleasantly surprised how similar it is. For the most part I find it workable but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to enable the toolbar with icons for saving files, building the solution, starting the application etc. How do I enable and configure it? I'm using MonoDevelop Version 7.8.4 (Build 2)

I want something like this:

[image: VS Toolbar Icons]

Right now my Monodevelop looks like this:

[image: Monodevelopmo]

Comment: Waste no time on it please, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b

Comment: oh okay thank you